# How using Thread pool won't crash Host resources over creating your own threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I am still a little confused about choosing using thread pool over creating my own threads.

I'm aware of the performance issue creating my own threads(creating, execution garbage collector collecting for each one I create), so no need to bring this up

the point is, if I abstract the number of created threads using thread pool, (I don't define thread limit), how does CLR know how many is enough?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime has a predefined number of worker threads that runs, I think the default is 10. It will queue up your requests for work to be done until there is an unoccupied thread in the pool. This is a very easy and fairly safe model for multithreading but you may want to look into 'async/await' as it can utilizes several concurrency models and abstracts te ugliness .

Answer (score 0):

The .NET run-time automatically selects a reasonable number of maximum threads based on the number of cores and other factors, but you can set this number yourself if you have special needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx

Answer (score 0):

thread pool **wont crash** if the system will exhaust the resources. thread pool will wait until the next thread is available to run your request (whatever it might be).

however would like to note a code which can exhaust the max available threadsis 99.5% is badly written or incorrect.

Comment: so pretty much I totally abstract the quantity of threads created?

Comment: yes............. but the question really is that - will it crash or not. the answer is - it wont...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `QueueUserWorkItem`. The keyword here is '**queue**'.

Queues a method for execution. The method executes when a thread pool thread becomes **available**.

ThreadPool provides a pool of threads that can be used to execute tasks, post work items, process asynchronous I/O, wait on behalf of other threads, and process timers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx

ie: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((i)=> Console.WriteLine("Hello"));`